Datafactory powerquery datetime not working
In datafactory when working with api extraction i put into a csv in blobstorage, i want to perform some powerquery statements. Now the first thing i want to do is change type from dates to datetime. But i get the following error:
Before:

after:

error code:





see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1251173/unsupported-constant-null-error-for-a-power-query

@horseyride see edit, it works but it shows error values in column. And datetimezone not working

I have tried the same expression with similar data and ended up with same error.

If you click on the error, it will show the actual reason for that error.

As per the Documentation,

UserQuery : Expression.Error: The transformation logic is not supported as it requires dynamic access to rows of data, which cannot be scaled out.

This error only occurs when the incoming data or current functions are not as per the ADF power query. Currently, not all M functions are supported in this. Check the same documentation to know about supported M functions in ADF power query.
To convert your input data into datetime format, first use below expression.
Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"mydate", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ".", 0), type text}})

This will extract the string before the '.' so that the input data format supports in this.

After this step, use the above expression and now you can see it will convert the input data into datetime format.
Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted text before delimiter", {{"mydate",each DateTime.FromText(_, [Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Culture = "en-us"]), type datetime}})


